# What optimization method can I use instead of Baysian Optimization for non-parametric online learning algorithm?

Tags: optimization, bayesian, online-machine-learning

In a problem I am working on, the problem is solved using the Baysian optimiztion for non-parametric online learning.

My question is: which other methods' performance can outperform baysian optimization?

I haven't tried much about this since I'm a novice here!